# How to remove extra dash from virtual category page meta title

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, category-listing, virtualtype

I have a few virtual categories set up in my top menu. When I go to a specific brand the meta title on my browsers tab shows a dash character "-" before the Brand Name.

[image]

Looking for a solution where the meta title will just be "Ping" instead of "- Ping". I already looked at the SEO section in the corresponding categories and they are empty inheriting the name from the Categories name. Also keep in mind that this category does have a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I learned that my company is using a third party extension that uses a Template Manager. The template responsible for the handling of meta data had a hard coded dash in the wrong area. Easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked store view? Most of the time we ignore this. can you please it once if using single store then please tick the checkbox.